# Evaluating a set of algorithms based on daily performance

Tags: machine-learning, method-comparison

I work in a production system which can use three competing algorithms, say $A_1,A_2,A_3$ for a customer on a daily basis. On each day, for a given customer, the production system looks at how much revenue each algorithm generated per day whenever it was selected (average daily revenue) in the past week. Then for that customer, it chooses the algorithm which performed the best. To avoid being stuck on one algorithm for a customer, we choose the best 90% of the time and randomly choose from three of them rest of the time (we toss a biased coin). The problem is to evaluate each algorithm's performance over the entire set of customers to derive some stats to understand which is the best performing algorithm. A straightforward metric would be to look at the number of customers for which an algorithm is used for over time. The one with the highest number of customers will be performing the best in some sense. What are the other metrics I can look at which are sensible? Can I think of these algos as arms of a bandit which gives different rewards for a given customer?. In that case, is there any metric from that literature that I can make use of ?